# iText7 NoClassDefFoundError - PdfDocument (com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument)

Tags: java, eclipse, itext7

So, I'm working on something for my father to organize his files using iText 7 Community. I downloaded the cumulative file from [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.1.14) (i.e. not the "jars only" file) and have imported all of them into my eclipse project. **I am not using maven for this, as I have zero experience with it at this point**. When I run my code, trying to parse through a pdf of his, the PdfDocument class isn't being found. Snippets follow.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
...
// Parse each file
try {
    for(File file : files) {
        PdfDocument p = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));   // Error point
        var page = p.getPage(0);
        String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(page);
        // Code to visualize text so I know what format it comes out as
    }
```

Error is as follows.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument
```

I've gone through a number of the previous questions about this topic, but most of them revolve around maven. I just tried grabbing the source code for the PdfDocument file, but that gave me... many errors heh.

Any help is appreciated :)